# Automatically add text numbering not included in headings to pdf bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, automation, bookmarks

In the following example, I have added the belowpdfbookmark command of the hyperref package after the lettrine numbers to add these to the bookmarks manually.

How can I do this automatically, so that I don't have to add the belowpdfbookmark command after every instance of gChapter? Would I need to use the 'addtohook' option? And if so, how?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\gChapter}[1]{\lettrine{{{#1}}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sayings}
\gChapter{1}\belowpdfbookmark{1}{one}
\lipsum[2]
\gChapter{2}\belowpdfbookmark{2}{two}
\lipsum[3]
\gChapter{3}\belowpdfbookmark{3}{three}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question really: `\chapter` does use bookmarks with `hyperref` already, you want to add bookmarks for something like numbered paragraphs with your  `\gchapter` macro?

Comment: Yes, maybe the question needs to be edited.

Comment: The format is that of the Bible, with each Bible book divided up into numbered text units (the Bible chapters=gChapter). Each text unit comprises of a number of (not numbered) paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by the comments you want to numbered manually, you can use this. The counter is there to get unique bookmark names.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcounter{gChapter}[chapter]
\newcommand{\gChapter}[1]{\par\refstepcounter{gChapter}\belowpdfbookmark{#1}{\thechapter.\thegChapter}\lettrine{#1}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sayings}
\gChapter{1}
\lipsum[2]
\gChapter{2}
\lipsum[3]
\gChapter{3}
\lipsum[4]

\chapter{Sayings}
\gChapter{1}
\lipsum[2]
\gChapter{2}
\lipsum[3]
\gChapter{1} %to check if the link is unique
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: this answers my question well, so I accepted it. However, I don't actually want the gChapters to be numbered automatically. How can I modify the example to accommodate this?

Comment: After second thoughts I've undone the acceptance of the answer. Although the answer is excellent, I need to number the gChapters manually and so keep the number in curly brackets after gChapters.

Comment: Then simply use #1 inside the argument instead of \thegchapter and remove the \refstepcounter.  But if the numbering is not unique you will need another argument to get a unique bookmark name.

Comment: Thinking a bit: better keep the counter and use only #1 in the lettrine. Then you will get unique names and manual representation. I will edit the answer later.